# "Export directory" from package manifest

Tags: ros, manifest.xml, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting the following warning:

```
[rosbuild] WARNING: the file /Users/nick/.../externalLibs.cmake is being included automatically.  This behavior is deprecated.  The package containing that file should instead export the directory containing the file, and you should use rosbuild_include() to include the file explicitly.
```

How does one "Export the directory containing the file" in the manifest?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10125/%22export-directory%22-from-package-manifest./) by [Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/237/nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2011-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists#rosbuild_include) for rosbuild_include() gives an example of what to do in the exporting package's manifest.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/237/nick/) on 2011-05-31**:
Thanks Brian!